# zsh menu select doesn't work

Tags: command-line, zsh

On my previous laptop when I did an `ls foobar/`  then I could navigate the menu and select things. Now I can't. Here's what I have, set up by Ubuntu 22.04:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' auto-description 'specify: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt %SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true
```

Here's what I added from my previous .zshrc, didn't fix the issue:

```
zmodload zsh/complist
bindkey -M menuselect ' ' accept-and-menu-complete
```

Comment: Can you please paste your .zshrc?

Comment: I thought I did?

Comment: zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
autoload -U compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zmodload zsh/complist
compinit

Please remove your previous zshrc and add these lines to your new zshrc and check if it works or not